# Linear and non linear equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have an equation I need to figure out. I apologize for my lack of knowledge and improper use of terms. My math skills are quite rusty.

One equation should be a derivative of the other.
The first equation is $A=P(1+\frac i {100})^n$

If I have a principal amount of 100 invested for 95 years at a rate of $7.5422 $ percent, the total amount of money after the 95 years will be $100{,}000$:

$$100\left(1+\frac{7.5422}{100}\right)^{95}=100,000$$

My question is what formula could I use in correlation to this formula if during these 95 years I also spent $5,000,000.00?

For this purpose the rate of spending is a constant however the rate of interest is always calculated based on what remains after the spending has been done. At no point in time do I invest any more than the original $100.

Basically this original investment earned 5,099,900.00 but the interest can only be calculated based on what exists after spending and so an end amount of $100,000 remains. 
Anyone have a clue as to what the equation would be and how it would look on a graph?

Comment: Thank you to the people that helped edit my post. Appreciate your help

Comment: Welcome to the math.SE. Could you please explain what you actually mean with spending 5 million dollars? How is this correlated to your savings after 95 years? Also  $100\left(1+\frac{7.5433}{100}\right)^{95}\approx100096.54>100000$...

Comment: After investing the original 100 dollars, I gained more than the interest rate of 7.5433 percent. I also gained 5,000,000 which I lived off of. The total saved amount at the end of 95 years was 100,000 dollars. The amount that I had to spend was always in correlation to the amount of interest that was made at any given time. The total profit was 5,000,000 plus the end result of 100,000 however the spending of the 5,000,000 started as soon as interest started to be save.

Comment: ex- if 7.54 dollars was kept after year one, a larger number contributing to the 5,000,000 was earned but was not included in the sum amount that would earn interest for the next year. This money was spent.

Comment: Let's see: You invest 100 dollar for a fixed interest rate at 7.5433 for a time period of 95 years, which gives you using the effect of compound interests at the end something slightly bigger than $100000$ dollar. That means you always invest the interest you gain each year right away back again. So you're not allowed to withdraw the 7.5433 dollar you gain after the first year for example

Comment: I suppose I will need to reword it to make more sense. Perhaps it should say 7.5433 percent is kept and reinvested from a total amount gained. The remainer of the total amount gained but always spent and never reinvested is that of 5,000,000

Comment: the amount spent in ratio to the amount gained is always the same. and so the amount reinvested in ratio to the percent gained is always the same. The interest earned is always compounded on itself however the amount spent is only compounded based on the interest itself and not compounded on amount spent from previous years